# running a task with 'rake' vs 'rails' causes high CPU usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, delayed-job

As the title suggests, we are witnessing an odd bug where running a task such as

```
rake jobs:clear
```

will cause a ruby process to run at nearly 100% CPU usage and won't close either. We then ran the same task but with 'rails' and the issue doesn't appear. In fact, we noticed that all our tasks that we normally run with 'rake' have a significantly smaller CPU load when ran with 'rails'. I can't fathom the logic of this one and welcome any insight.

If anyone stumbles across this with a similar issue then running tasks with 'rails' is a potential answer.

Comment: Are you using spring or similar gems? Could be that rake boots everything up which could take a while and rails already has everything `cached`. You could test that you could kill spring task and deactivate it and check the the runtime of both commands.

Comment: Maybe it's a version mismatch. Have you tried running it as `bundle exec rake ...`?

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I'll do some more digging and see if i can recreate the issue with spring stopped. I did not that the using spring stop did kill the process but I guess it doesn't mean it's necessarily linked to spring itself.